# How to create directory outside the folder in PHP , MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, upload

Ok, i am saving picx in a directory which saved in the admin folder. now i want to save the files outside of the admin folder but unable to do it. please help :)

upload.php

```
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }       
    $query="INSERT into upload_data (`postID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$postID','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
    $desired_dir="user_data";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
     mysql_query($query);           
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What errors/problems are you facing?

Comment: Why you do not save the file in the DB?

Comment: through this coding i can am having no problem but the directory is created in admin folder now i want to create this directory outside admin folder , i tried to put ../ as well but not working

Comment: **Stop** using deprected `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` whith prepared statement

Comment: ok i will try. @Jens now help me in this. i dont want to save in the database as its tough to create backup and store again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line :

```
$desired_dir="../user_data";
```

Comment: Don't be, sometime mind got stuck. By the way, you can give vote :)